# passing char by pointer and getting a different result

Tags: c++, gethostbyname

I am using gethostname to get the name of the computer I am working on.  In my main function I call it and get UBU24-PS-23 the correct name of my computer.  Then I call a function and that uses the gethostname and I get a different string.  In my main function gethostname returns 0 so it works, in my function it returns -1 so it fails.  Any ideas why?  Here is my code

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <sys/unistd.h>
 using namespace std;


int funToGetHostName(char * name, size_t len);
int main() {

char hostname[128];
char hostnameFunction[128];

int g = gethostname(hostname, sizeof hostname);
int r = funToGetHostName(hostnameFunction, sizeof hostnameFunction);
cout<<"My hostname: %s\n"<< hostname<< " "<< g<<endl;
cout<<"My hostnameFunction: %s\n"<< hostnameFunction<< " "<< r;

return 0;
}

int funToGetHostName(char * name, size_t len){
    return gethostname(name, sizeof len);
}
```

Comment: sizeof(len) is the same as sizeof(size_t). And size_t is (probably) either 32 or 64 bits wide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int funToGetHostName(char * name, size_t len){
    return gethostname(name, sizeof len);
}
```

`sizeof len` is likely to be much smaller than you expect.

Instead, you want:

```
    return gethostname(name, len);
```

since you already passed in the buffer length while calling your function.

Answer (score 2):

There is an error in:

```
int funToGetHostName(char * name, size_t len){
    return gethostname(name, sizeof len);
                             //^^^^^ This is not 128.
}
```

You need

```
int funToGetHostName(char * name, size_t len){
    return gethostname(name, len);
}
```